# How to communicate between Service and Viewcontroller?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I'm pretty new to iOS and swift development. A lot of swift + firebase tutorials out there, the firebase stuff *(such as authentication, fetching and saving data)* is done in the ViewController. As far as I got on learning swift, this leads directly to the problem of "Massive View Controllers". In some tutorials they use classes like "DataService.swift" and access them as a singleton:

```
class DataService {

   static let dataService: DataService = DataService()

   func createUser(FIRUser: user) {}
   ...
}
```

BUT these classes have no communication with the view controller when they're done with e.g. creating the user. Let me be more specific. I guess it should like this:

1. User taps login button.
2. Then, ViewController calls dataService.createUser(user) which handles the login stuff and saves the user data to firebase.
3. If it's finished it should communicate to the view controller, that it's finished.
4. ViewController checks the result of the createUser() and navigates the user to another view.

How can i do this? At the moment i'm using the delegation pattern. Is this a good way to handle this stuff?

Comment: you need to use delegate-protocol methods for communicating between viewControllers and singleton.

Comment: There are a number of different ways you can handle this. You can use NotificationCenter to send event messages across your app, you could use the aforementioned delegate/protocol patterns, you could add completion blocks where necessary, etc. Question is way too broad to give a direct answer - I would suggest researching each of those to determine which method is best for your needs and then asking specific questions about it if you find yourself stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
// User.swift
struct User {
    // Declare necessary properties.
    // Such as firstName, lastName, email, etc.
}

// AuthenticationService.swift
protocol AuthenticationService {
    func createUser(user: User, completion: (Error?, User?) -> Void)
}

// AuthServiceProvider.swift
class AuthServiceProvider: AuthenticationService {

    func createUser(user: User, completion: (Error?, User?) -> Void) {
        // Do the necessary work here. 
        // Convert user to an instance of 'FIRUser' if necessary.
        // Use the completion block when you are done.
    }
}

// RegisterViewController.swift
class RegisterViewController: UIViewController {

    var service = AuthServiceProvider()        

    @IBAction func didTapRegisterButton(sender: UIButton) {
        var user = User()
        // Fill the necessary properties to be included.
        // Then call the 'createUser' function.
        service.createUser(user: user) { (error, user) -> Void in
            // This is where you are redirected upon completion.
            // Handle always the error if there is.
            // If there is none, navigate to your next scene/view.
        }
    }
}
```

By the way, as much as possible, just avoid implementing a Singleton Class. This kind of implementation might give you a hard time on doing some unit tests.

Regarding with your concern on "Massive View Controller", you can consider on modularizing your project. But right now, I would suggest that it is better to experience this "MVC" problem than avoiding it.